# How to loop an HTTP request and update the variables each time in Jmeter BeanShell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have 2 HTTP request: One to GET data from an api and the other to POST data to the api.

The GET request brings several users in JSON. The POST request requires to 1 request per user. Hence I need to:

1. Loop the same POST request several times depending on the number of users (already did this by using a while controller that checks the number of users from the JSON response).
2. For each POST request, I need the variables used in such request to be updated depending on the user's information inside the JSON response.

The approach I am attempting is to use BeanShell PreProcessor inside the POST request but I'm having troubles with it.

Suppose one variable is called ${name} in the request body of the POST. I am using a JSON Extractor PostProcessor (On the GET request) path: "Travelers[0].FirstName" that returns the first name of the first user but then I need the second user's name (Travelers[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUCA7.png).FirstName) to be assigned to the same variable ${name} before the POST request is sent and so on with every single user.

- I want to make a for loop like this:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfTravelers; i++) {
   vars.put("Name", Travelers[i].FirstName) 
   }
  ```

The problem is that I do not know how to call a JSON path from a JSON response of another previous request. Is there a way to reference the jsonpath to the specific JSON response or a way to save the whole JSON response in a variable and then find the specific value inside that variable as a JSON path.

I have tried this with the JSON extractor but the problem is that if I use the path: Travelers[*].FirstName, it will actually get all the names on the JSON but the variable ${name} will only store ONE name, not all of them as an array that I can later access in my for loop with a normal variable ${name[i]}. That is why I need to access the JSON path from the BeanSheall.

Here a sample of the JSON response:

```
{
"Travelers":
[
    {
        "FirstName":"VICTOR",
        "Surname":"ORREGO",
        "Key":"1.1",
        "PassengerRPH":1,
        "TypeCode":"ADT"
    },
    {
        "FirstName":"JULIO",
        "Surname":"OZAETA",
        "Key":"2.2",
        "PassengerRPH":2,
        "TypeCode":"ADT"
    }
]
}
```

This is the PostProcesor [JSON Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUCA7.png) at the GET request that I'm using. it is currently assigning the first name it gets from the JSON response (Victor) to the variable ${Name}
I need that in the next iteration (of the POST Request) the variable ${Name} to return the next name in that path, which is Julio.

Comment: Can you Add your JSON response here..

It would be very easy to do with JSON extractor

Comment: just added the JSON response and the JSON extractor I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution..

1. Add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to the get request .. use match no -1 to store all Firstnames as show below.
   [image]

i'm extracting all Firstnames and storing it in JMeter variables with a single JSON extractor
 2. To the same get request add a [JSR223 Post processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and set the counter value to 1

```
vars.put("counter","1");
```

3. Add a [while loop](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/jmeter-while-controller/) to the test plan and add the following condition to the while loop.

> ${__javaScript(parseInt(${counter})<=parseInt(vars.get("FirstName_matchNr")),)}

4.To the post request add a [JSR223 Pre Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)  and add the following code

```
vars.put("name",vars.get("FirstName_"+vars.get("counter")));
```

This will store FirstName_Matchno's value in name variable.

4. Add a [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to the POST Request and increment the counter.

> int counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter")) +1;
>       vars.put("counter",Integer.toString(counter));

You can see in the results its substituting a different name on each iteration of loop

[image]

Let me know if it helps..

Comment: This works perfectly, just one more question, I'm trying to set an if controller inside the while loop. The conditions is  "${TypeCode}" == "ADT" then execute the request.  for some reason, it is not working for me.

Comment: Victor I have answered your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033572/controller-inside-while-controller-in-jmeter/51034907#51034907